# Php parse error in Drupal 7 application

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, parse-error

I tried to run a Drupal 7 installation on my local environment which previously worked totally fine. I use Mac OS X. When requesting the website locally the browser shows:

> Parse error: parse error in /Library/WebServer/Documents/.../xxx.module
>   on line 7

Line 7 is

```
$variables['path'] = $base_url . "/sites/default/files/" . explode('public://',$file->uri)[1]
```

OR it returns an error with the code:

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

The apache error file shows:

> child pid 2114 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

php -v returns

> PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2013 19:05:08) Copyright (c) 1997-2013
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend
>   Technologies

The code seems not to be wrong. It's exactly the same running on another machine.

Comment: What about the code on line 7 ?? ...maybe you are missing some php extension or something like that

Comment: That is line 7: $variables['path'] = $base_url . "/sites/default/files/" . explode('public://',$file->uri)[1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array dereferencing was [added in PHP5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Your server has v5.3.26, so this

```
explode('public://',$file->uri)[1];
```

isn't valid syntax.

You either need to upgrade to 5.4 ([Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) makes that easy), or change your code:

```
$parts = explode('public://',$file->uri);
$variables['path'] = $base_url . "/sites/default/files/" . $parts[1];
```

Comment: I upgraded my Php to the newest version and the parser error is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [file_create_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7).

```
$variables['path'] = file_create_url($file->uri);
```